# Powershelll self-signed certificate generation in .crt and .key files

Tags: powershell, ssl

I am trying to generate self-signed certificate with Powershell. I want 2 files for the certificate which are **.crt** and **.key**. I am seeing Powershell [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps) which generated certificates and [export docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/export-certificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

In the `Export-Certificate` command their is no such way to generate **.crt** and **.key** files for the certificate. How to do it.

Comment: In the crypto world a file extension does not uniquely identify the format of the data. This problem is made worse by Microsoft's terrible documentation. Thus, saying you want `.crt` and `.key` files doesn't really help. What would help is supplying the context where you need to use your ".crt" and ".key" files so we can figure out the exact format that's needed.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk i want to use it on apache where private key is needed. I want to use .crt file for ssl.